# Can I use "aspect" in this context instead of "regard"

Tags: grammar

Context:

I would reply to your email after 10 days.
I would like to appreciate your patience in this regard.

Can I use "aspect" instead of "regard".

I think both will mean same but I need explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is it's *not* a good idea to replace ***regard*** with ***aspect*** in your specific context.

Whichever word you used, it would be a metaphoric extension from the core meaning, which in both cases centres around the concept of a ***perspective, vantage point, point of view***.

Note that *[seen] from this aspect* is a credible (though less common) alternative to *...in this regard* when referring to *a specific way of looking at something*. But in OP's context we're actually referring to *everything about the thing itself*, not just some particular way of looking at it.

Idiomatically, only ***in this regard*** or ***in this respect*** are well-established for the extended meaning *concerning this matter*.

Comment: What is meant by OP in your answer. Confused!

Comment: OP = *original poster* or *original post* (***you***, or your ***posted question***, whichever makes most sense in the specific context).